# How can I have an Input element in my Visual Studio Code sidebar, when coding for a extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

[image: example of Input]

How can I code my VSC extension so that I have an input at the sidebar just like the image, where the input is at the bottom of it.

Thank you!

The closest that I got is it to have a child element of TreeView that will display a string. But the API says that an InputBox is not supported. So the only solution that I got is to have an vscode.window.showInputBox() that will appear at the top of the VSC IDE.

This is what I got and what I want.

[image]